# Using Sockets in Python: Only runs correctly when using IDLE. Does not run correctly in CMD

Tags: python, sockets, python-2.7, windows-7-x64

I am trying to execute a simple socket communication script and having some difficulties when trying to run the script using the command prompt. I am using Windows 7 64-bit with Python 2.7.5 AMD 64.

The script works fine when I execute it with IDLE, however when use the command prompt it just sits there twiddling it's thumbs.

Here is the code that I am using to try to troubleshoot the problem:

```
from socket import *

print "Hello World"
tcp_ip = '192.168.1.241'
tcp_port = 2001    
buffer_size = 11
plc_socket = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM)
plc_socket.bind((tcp_ip, tcp_port))        
plc_socket.listen(1)       
socket_conn, socket_addr = plc_socket.accept()
print "Connection Accepted"
socket_conn.shutdown(1)             
plc_socket.close()
```

When I run the code by using the command line, I do get the "Hello World" and it does everything before the SOCKET_CONN, SOCKET_ADDR line and then just sits there.

I have already done the following:

1. Set my windows path information to point to the Python installation directory.
2. Uninstalled any other versions of Python that were on my machine.
3. Tried script on other machines (identical build) to see if it works. (it does)
4. Verified that I am running the correct version of Python from the command line.
5. Scratched my head in confusion.

Any wisdom on the matter would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Why are all your variable names shouting at me?

Comment: Meanwhile, are you sure it's blocking on `accept` and not blocking (or erroring out) sooner than that? Also, how are you testing it?

Comment: Perhaps I should edit my code to be more calming. It never actually errors out, it just sits there doing nothing. And yes, I am sure. I tested by printing text after each line. It got to the "Socket_Conn" line and then didn't keep going.

Comment: I meant how are you testing the script? `nc 192.168.1.241 2001`? Putting `http://192.168.1.241:2001` into a web browser?

Comment: I have a PLC sending a connection request to 192.168.1.241, port 2001. I just tested it using the `http://192.168.1.241:2001` method. It worked! I will have to examine things on the PLC side to see if that's what's causing the problem.

Comment: I don't know what you mean by PLC. (Presumably not a programmable logic controller chip on which you've implemented a TCP/IP client in terms on logic gates?) But yeah, this definitely seems like a client-side problem, not a problem with your code.

Comment: @abarnert Actually yes, a programmable logic controller with a TCP/IP logic block used to send data to the python script.

Comment: Wow, I didn't realize people were using PLCs for such complicated things nowadays. Cool. So… are you using the same PLC when you test on each computer? How is it connected up? Also, to rule out the possibility of any problems in your Python script, you might want to set up some other server (`nc -l 192.168.1.241 2001` if you have a BSD-syntax netcat; slightly different with GNU-syntax or Hobbit-syntax netcat) to make sure it has the same problem.

Comment: @abarnert Netcat is revealing that the PLC is sending data via the correct port, but for some reason the script is still not accepting the connection when I run it from the cmd prompt. And yes, I am using the same PLC with each computer through Ethernet and one is working and one is not.

Comment: Could there be a system-level firewall blocking port 192.168.1.241:2001 from non-local connections? In other words, set up netcat to serve port 2001 on one machine and netcat to it from the other, then try the other way around, and see if it works the same in both directions.

Comment: @abarnert You are correct, my friend. For some reason the system firewall was only blocking the connection when the script was executed from the cmd prompt. Thanks for your help! I really appreciate it.

Comment: You should probably write your own answer and accept it, or delete your question. Or, if you want me to write an answer to accept, I can do that. (Any of those are better for future readers/searchers, and for your rep, than leaving a question lying around with no answers.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem has been solved.

It turns out that a local network firewall was blocking the TCP/IP connection when the script was being run by the command line or executed directly.

I turned off the firewall and the script worked perfectly.